# How to encode/decode tokens in `vertexai` for pre-trained (bison) chat models?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

Is there a tiktoken-equivalent either within `vertexai` or `google.cloud.aiplatform` for pretrained chat and text models such as bison?

I want to be able to count tokens *before* sending a request so that I can programmatically determine which and how much information to place into the `context`, `examples`, and `message_history` properties.

The closest thing I can find is this reference to an API endpoint that returns the billable tokens used: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/get-token-count . I'd rather not have to make a slow HTTPS roundtrip just to get a count.

Also, the `send_message` exception isn't clear when the input size is the cause which makes it unusable as a signal for truncation. The exception is this rather vague message:

> 400 The request cannot be processed. The most likely reason is that the provided input exceeded the model's input token limit.

Comment: I haven't tested yet but API documentation shows "compute tokens" function: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.llm_utility_service.LlmUtilityServiceClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_llm_utility_service_LlmUtilityServiceClient_compute_tokens